# Duplicate nodes after node import using the Node Export module

Tags: importing-exporting

I ran into a major problem with the Node Export module... on my remote site I use drush to export all nodes of a certain type into a text file. Then I move that file to my local site and import the file, also using drush. The problem is that **new** nodes are created during the import, so that existing nodes gets duplicated. And yes I have checked the option "Create a new revision of the existing node" (if the node exists).

A very strange thing is that if I export the nodes locally and then re-import them again locally, this does not happen. But my remote site is identical with the local one, and the nodes do have the same node IDs. I have checked and double checked that.

I have also looked in the file itself before import and the node IDs are correct.

Does anyone have an idea why the export file from the remote site is treated differently during import, so that nodes get duplicated?

Comment: This sounds like a bug best discussed in the Node Export issue queue

Comment: You are right, I have posted this question in the Node Export issue queue. Also, in case anyone else has the same problem. Always go to the config page and click Create missing UUIDs before exporting the database locally and loading it on the remote site. Also double check with devel that the UUIDs actually are identical on some local and remote existing nodes, before actually carrying out the export-import procedure.